# How to retrieve git commit history for specific time period with cURL?

Tags: json, git, curl, github, github-api

I am trying to retrieve commit history as JSON and output in a txt file.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/commits > commitHistory.txt
```

With above curl commend, I only get the 1st page of the commit history. I would like to retrieve full commit history or maybe set a date range when doing it. How should I do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't clone the repository and just `git log remotes/branch`? If you're trying to script this, looking into [parsing JSON with UNIX tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `since` and `until` parameters to get commits only for specific time period:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/commits?since=2016-11-01T00:00:00Z&until=2016-11-01T23:59:59Z
```

For details: See [api doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) .

Comment: i need the same for ```curl https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo/events``` the same command is not working

Answer (score 2):

API requests from GitHub are automatically paginated for large result sets, so you'll need to inspect the `Link:` header and make further requests while ever there are more results. The [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) offers more information:

> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. You can specify further pages with the `?page` parameter. For some resources, you can also set a custom page size up to 100 with the `?per_page` parameter. Note that for technical reasons not all endpoints respect the `?per_page` parameter, see [events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) for example.
>
> `curl 'https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=2&per_page=100'`
>
> Note that page numbering is 1-based and that omitting the ?page parameter will return the first page.
>
> For more information on pagination, check out our guide on [Traversing with Pagination](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination).

You could also do this using a Python library like `github3.py` (or equivalent), which will handle pagination for you.

In terms of a specific date range, [philipjkim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40925280/246534) is correct: use the `since` and `until` parameters.