# Obtain Github Gists within date range (= time period)

Tags: rest, github, pagination, github-api, gist

Is there a way to find all gists created/modified between two past dates? In the Github Gist API there is only the keyword `since`, see [Gist API](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#list-all-public-gists). The keyword `until` (e.g. from [Commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits)) does not seem available for gists.

Is there perhaps a different way to obtain all gists between two dates? Similar to [How to retrieve git commit history for specific time period with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923047/how-to-retrieve-git-commit-history-for-specific-time-period-with-curl), just for gists.

I've tried getting gist data using *pagination* (i.e. looping over the returned pages), using URLs like 
`https://api.github.com/gists?since=2019-01-01T21:30:11Z&page=1&per_page=001&until=2019-01-02T16:55:11Z`
 but it is always limited to 3000 items (and the `until` keyword is unfortunately ignored). Requesting pages above that 3000 threshold returns:

```
`GithubException: 422 {'message': 'In order to keep the API fast for everyone, pagination is limited for this resource.`
```

Any help appreciated.